# Can't get margins to show in CSS

Tags: css, css-float, margins

I have added schema markup to my website, and I have placed it at the bottom on my page in the footer. On my CSS it says

```
#copyright {
    float:left;
    margin:13px 10px 0 23;
    width:380px
}
```

But when I browse it through [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) it doesn't show the margin, only the float and width. It was showing it before, and all I changed was the first and last numbers of the margin trying to get the schema markup exactly where I wanted it.

Comment: Can you please also show some HTML? Just so that we could try it out. Or maybe a link to your website

Comment: Do you have any other rules being applied to that element that might be overriding these rules? Also, `23` alone is an invalid value -- it needs a unit.

Comment: Could you add the unit `px` to the last number `23`?

Comment: If one of the answers was most helpful, go ahead and mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I see is that the 23 in your margin list does have 'px' on it. Could that be the issue? Try updating it to:

```
margin:13px 10px 0 23px;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors:

**This:**

```
#copyright {
    float:left;
    margin:13px 10px 0 23;
    width:380px
}
```

**Should Be:**

```
#copyright {
    float:left;
    margin:13px 10px 0 23px;
    width:380px;
}
```

*Notice the missing semicolon after width. This could cause the previous styles from being read. Also the left margin won't be read because you didn't define a unit.*

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#copyright {
    float:left;
    margin:13px 10px 0 23px;
    width:380px;
}
```

Comment: That fixed it! I figured it was something simple. You guys are great. I am brand new here but hope that I can make a contribution with my limited knowledge base. lol Thank you!